# VirtualBox / Ubuntu 10.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I created a virtual machine using VirtualBox 3.2 and Ubuntu Server 10.04 x64. Everything works fine. I logged in. I mounted the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file. However, I can't for the life of me find where in the operating system this was done so I can get the additions installed. I've tried /media, /cdrom, /mnt, etc...

I'm obviously new at this. Can someone help figure out how to install the guest additions and how to locate the mounted file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

sudo mount /dev/scd0 /cdrom

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will have trouble installing the guest additions anyway. They require the full Ubuntu desktop package, that means X and everything...

You can try Installing the desktop stuff, then the additions and finally remove the desktop stuff again. I am not sure if this really works though, I've heard of people who run into problems afterwards.

Why do you need the guest additions anyway on a server? Won't you be accessing it via ssh anyway? (It's what I do with my Ubuntu 10.04 Server virtual machine...)

Comment: True regarding server and the guest additions. I ended up installing desktop. The reason I originally thought the additions would help was due to the ridiculous redraw rate when using the VM terminal to log in. Scrolling through long listings was slow, to say the least. I switched to the desktop edition which with the additions works fine. I suppose I could go back to server and as you said SSH to it.

Answer (score 0):

The guest additions will report that they are not installing the X additions (mouse integration, display resizing) if they cannot find X.
However, the other modules are installed and are useful for a server environment.
These support Shared Folders, keeping system clock more accurate, and the new interface for executing apps within the guest from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 and this solved the screen resolution problem